# Show Poster Image after the Video finishes in JWPlayer

Tags: css, jwplayer

I am trying to show Poster Image after the video is finished in JWPlayer.

The problem is that after the video finishes, it shows me this big black box on my white site, which looks like a bad unwanted thing.

This is how it looks:-

[image]

So I was wondering if I could place a poster or just change that black box white.

Here is my JS through which I am calling JWPlayer.

```
jwplayer("myvideo").setup({
    autostart: true,
    controlbar: {position: 'none'},
    skin: "scripts/vendor/jwplayer/minima.zip",

    flashplayer: "scripts/vendor/jwplayer/player-licensed.swf",
    image: "../images/poster.png",
    file: $scope.getCurrentSlide().video

});
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: As long as you are using the image variable, it should show the image when the video is over. Can I see a link?